# calculate date in 1 min interval postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table like this:

```
create table simulation_book_data 
(
    dt date,
    t time without time zone,
    price numeric   
)
```

the lines look like this:

```
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:37.7663" 2
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:38.7663" 5
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:39.7663" 0
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:40.7663" 9
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:41.7663" 3
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:42.7663" 7
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:43.7663" 5
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:44.7663" 6
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:45.7663" 3
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:46.7663" 1
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:47.7663" 2
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:48.7663" 5
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:49.7663" 8
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:50.7663" 9
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:51.7663" 4
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:52.7663" 5
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:53.7663" 6
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:54.7663" 6
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:55.7663" 7
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:56.7663" 8
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:57.7663" 9
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:58.7663" 7
"2021-11-17"    "06:39:59.7663" 8
"2021-11-17"    "06:40:00.7663" 9
"2021-11-17"    "06:40:01.7663" 1
```

I want to sum the price column per minute, but couldn't find how to do range with time (not timestamp)

Comment: Any particular reason for storing date and time in separated columns?

Comment: @JimJones I'm loading it from a file and the date is like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the function `sum()` with a group by using `date_trunc`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute',dt+t),sum(price) 
FROM simulation_book_data
GROUP BY 1;

     date_trunc      | sum 
---------------------+-----
 2021-11-17 06:39:00 | 125
 2021-11-17 06:40:00 |  10
(2 rows)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=84f0bf383a0267dc430656eae3da6a2f)

Answer (score 0):

you can use sum() as a window function, to_char converts a timestamp to a format 'HH24:MI' omitting seconds

```
select distinct on (dt, to_char(sbd.t,  'HH24:MI'::text))
sbd.dt,
sbd.t,
to_char(sbd.t,  'HH24:MI'::text),
sum(price) over (partition by dt, to_char(sbd.t,  'HH24:MI'::text))
from simulation_book_data sbd
```

result:

```
2021-11-17  06:39:37    06:39   125
2021-11-17  06:40:00    06:40   10
```